# Why shouldn't there be a '&' in the function cuscomp's parameters?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Here is the code:

```
    bool cuscomp(pair<double,int> x, pair<double, int> y){
        if(x.first == y.first) return x.second < y.second;
        else return x.first > y.first;
    }

int main()
{
    vector<pair<double,int>>s;
    s.push_back(make_pair(//dosomethings));
    sort(s.begin(),s.end(),cuscomp);
 }
```

The above code works perfectly fine.
But when i change the function `cuscomp` passing parameters to

```
bool cuscomp(pair<double,int> &x, pair<double, int> &y)  //tried to call using reference
```

it gives me an error.
Why can't we call the pair using call by reference method?

Comment: Hint: should a comparator be able to change the things it compares? If yes, what would the result of the comparison mean?

Comment: With current versions of GCC, clang, and MSVC, it compiles just fine with `&`. Which compiler rejects it?

Comment: Just as a side note: don't rely on floating-point equality comparison via `==` or `!=`.